# unknown type name, pero está incluido

Tags: c, struct

Creé esta estructura de tipo **stUser** en ***users.h***:

```
#ifndef USERS_H_INCLUDED
#define USERS_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
    int id;           // Autoincremental
    char nya[50];     // Nombre y apellido
    char mail[50];
    int celular;
    char password[8]; // Contraseña con máx de 8 caracteres
    int estado;       // 0. Inactivo | 1. Activo
    } stUser;
```

Y una de tipo ***nodoListaUsers*** que utilizo en la función que me presenta error.

```
typedef struct
{
    stUser user;
    nodoArbolPelis * playlist;
    struct nodoListaUsers * sig;
} nodoListaUsers;

// ... Funciones ...

#endif // USERS_H_INCLUDED
```

En ***users.c*** la función para cargarla:

```
    stUser registrarUser(nodoListaUsers * listaAlta, nodoListaUsers * listaBaja)
{
    stUser nuevoUser;
    int verificadorPass, verificador;

    nuevoUser.id = idUltimoUsuario(listaAlta,listaBaja)+1;

    printf(">Ingrese su nombre y apellido:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nuevoUser.nya);

    verificador = consultaExistenciaUser(listaAlta, listaBaja, nuevoUser.nya);

    while(verificador == 1)
    {
        printf(">Nombre ya existente. Ingrese otro.\n");
        gets(nuevoUser.nya);
        verificador = consultaExistenciaUser(listaAlta, listaBaja, nuevoUser.nya);
    }

    printf(">Ingrese su email: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nuevoUser.mail);

    printf(">Ingrese su numero de celular: \n");
    scanf("%i", &nuevoUser.celular);

    printf(">Ingrese una contrasenia (7 caracteres max.): \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nuevoUser.password);

    verificadorPass = verificarLongPass(nuevoUser.password);
    while(verificadorPass == 0)
    {
        printf(">Recuerde que su contrasenia puede tener hasta 7 caracteres.\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nuevoUser.password);
        verificadorPass = verificarLongPass(nuevoUser.password);
    }

    nuevoUser.estado = 1;

    return nuevoUser;
}
```

La función ***registrarUser*** no debería presentar problemas en sí. Con lo que estoy teniendo errores es con stUser en la función como tal.
Al intentar ejecutar el programa, me marca el siguiente error en la línea `stUser registrarUser(nodoListaUsers * listaAlta, nodoListaUsers * listaBaja)` de la declaración de la función:

```
C:\Users\lurdr\Desktop\Lab2PrimeVideo\users.c|7|error: unknown type name 'stUser'|
```

Y en varias líneas más tampoco reconoce a stUser. Así lo incluyo en el ***main***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "users.h"
#include "users.c"
```

En ***users.c***:

```
#include "users.h"
```

De todas formas no reconoce mi estructura y arroja ese error.

Comment: Una pregunta tonta ... ¿Te has acordado de añadir `#endif` al final de `users.h`?

Comment: Por otro lado, en `main` no tienes que hacer un include a `users.c`. Ese enlace es tarea del enlazador o _linker_

Comment: Me suena haber visto una pregunta similar, no se si al verla en primera instancia te recomendé este articulo [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Si ya lo hice, te recomendaría que repasaras la parte final. "*¡Asegúrate de que el ejemplo reporta el problema en la actualidad!*". Pasando de que en tu descripción llamas a tus archivos `usuario` y en el código los llamas `users`, al crear los archivos con el contenido que indicas, no da el error que dices que da. El error es que no encuentra `nodoListaUsers`.

Comment: Pero el ver que haces `#include "users.c"` en `main.c`, me hace pensar que el problema es que no entiendes como trabajar con varios archivos en C. No hay ningún motivo por el que tendrías que incluir un archivo `.c`. Te recomendaría que repasaras tu material de clase.

Comment: Dejando de incluir el "users.c" en main.c no reconoce algunas funciones del "users.h". No sé por qué.

Comment: Si no las reconoce es porque no están declaradas en el `users.h`. Las cabeceras sirven precisamente para eso, para hacer declaraciones de tipos y funciones que vas a utilizar en otras partes del código

Comment: Está users.h en un path que es incluido?

Comment: @Duston si haces el `#include` con comillas, el compilador buscará dicho archivo en el mismo directorio que el archivo que tiene el `#include`